# Count occurrences with SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have following audit table:

```
oprcod | extm | insdt
---------------------
CLOSE  | 300  | 10-26-2017
CLOSE  | 212  | 10-26-2017
CLOSE  | 96   | 10-26-2017
RATE   | 25   | 10-26-2017
RATE   | 118  | 10-26-2017
RATE   | 115  | 10-27-2017
RATE   | 199  | 10-27-2017
RATE   | 89   | 10-27-2017
LABEL  | 120  | 10-26-2017
LABEL  | 500  | 10-26-2017
LABEL  | 700  | 10-27-2017
LABEL  | 450  | 10-27-2017
LABEL  | 110  | 10-27-2017
LABEL  | 15   | 10-27-2017
LABEL  | 600  | 10-27-2017
LABEL  | 111  | 10-27-2017
LABEL  | 350  | 10-27-2017
LABEL  | 45   | 10-27-2017
```

I am trying to write a SQL that will give me a total number of each oprcod occurrences by insdt. Furthermore, I want to break down the total by 0-100 extm, 100-200 extm and 200+extm (not double dipping/counting). With this I can know how execution times fall for each operation did by day and if we have performance problems. Also, its a easy way to measure KPI's.

Output:

```
insdte      | oprcod | total | 0to100 | 100to200 | 200+
--------------------------------------------------------
10-26-2017  | CLOSE  |   3   |    1   |     0    |  2
10-26-2017  | RATE   |   2   |    1   |     1    |  0
10-27-2017  | RATE   |   3   |    1   |     2    |  0
10-26-2017  | LABEL  |   2   |    0   |     1    |  1
10-27-2017  | LABEL  |   8   |    2   |     2    |  4
```

Your help is much appreciated. I have done some testing with some SQL and I am very close but just cant get there because I keep missing something. I will share my approach once I have it buttoned up.

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  SQL Server <> Oracle.  Which one do you use?????

Comment: Post your query.

Comment: I was really looking for both or either as a suggestion, which is why I added both tags. Sorry for the frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select insdt, oprcod,
       count(*) as total,
       sum(case when extm between 0 and 99 then 1 else 0 end) as [0to99],
       sum(case when extm between 100 and 199 then 1 else 0 end) as [100to199],
       sum(case when extm >= 200 then 1 else 0 end) as [200+]
from your_table
group by insdt, oprcod
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you @juergen d

Comment: I was using sign function with combination of sum, but case worked much easier and intuitively.